# Vue.js v-if for attributes

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Let's say I have this code

```
table(my-attr="value")
    ...complex component Jade...
```

and I would like render that `my-attr` base on property delivered into component. Since v-if works on whole element I cannot do something like

```
table(my-attr="value", v-if="myProp")
table(v-else)
```

because I would have to duplicate all the code inside table.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `v-bind` or interpolate the value directly with `{{}}`

```
// (sorry, no jade)
<table v-bind:attribute1="someMethod" attribute2="{{anotherMethod}}">
```

Now `someMethod` and `anotherMethod` should be data, computed properties, or methods of your component, and should return either the attribute's desired value or `false`. In the latter case, the attribute will not be added to the element at all.

**Update:** Note that interpolations in attributes have been removed in Vue 2